# creating a 3d surface graph in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following data:

[image]

I'm trying to plot x=long, y=short, z=balance

I've done it like this:

```
fig.add(go.Scatter3d(x=results['long'], y=results['short'], z=results['balance']))
```

and I get something like that:

[image]

what I am really looking for is a surface, like this example:

[image]

so, following the example's code, I did:

```
fig.add_surface(x=results['long'], y=results['short'], z=results['balance'], row=2, col=1)
```

but:

[image]

not only it doesn't display any data, it seems to totally ignore the subplot layout and draws over everything.

here is the complete code:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, specs=[[{'type': 'xy'}], [{'type': 'scene'}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=series1['timestamp'], y=series1['data'], line_color='red', name='series 1'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=series2['timestamp'], y=series2['data'], line_color='blue', name='series 2'), row=1, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="USD", row=1, col=1)

fig.add_surface(x=results['long'], y=results['short'], z=results['balance'], row=2, col=1)
fig.show()
```

so, my questions are:

- how can I create a smooth surface from the data I have?
- what did I miss regarding the layout?

Comment: Were you able to plot it? I'm having the same issue. The problem for me is that my surface is a parametric surface, (x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)) so reshaping z in any of the standard ways will loose the functional relationship.

Comment: @RicardoAcuna, that was 2 years ago, I don't remember at all what the solution might have been, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Two answers:

1. `surface` traces accept a 2-d matrix for `z`
2. 3-d traces are plotted in a `layout.scene` object which is distinct from a 2-d cartesian subplot

Comment: Is there a graph with the hierarchy of objects and how the scene is assembled? I know it's kind of a newbie question, but I have a hard time to visualize what belongs to what and where every part fits in the pipeline

Comment: Not at the moment... I'm working on a high-level doc to explain the structure but we don't have it yet!

Answer (score -2):

Try 3D Surface plot from docs([here](https://plot.ly/python/3d-surface-plots/)). Below provide example of it. As I think, you can change `z_data` - and that's all, what you need:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

# Read data from a csv
z_data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z_data.values)])

fig.update_layout(title='Mt Bruno Elevation', autosize=False,
                  width=500, height=500,
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))

fig.show()
```